# Left tick marks remain in matplotlib despite call to tick_params and use of NullLocator

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've been struggling to remove the left tick marks from a matplotlib plot which has two subplots which share the x-axis.

If I just start with one plot, things behave as I would expect:

```
X = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
Y = np.sin(X)
Z = np.sin(2 * X)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])

ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax1.tick_params(axis='both',
                which='both',
                bottom='off',
                top='off',
                left='off',
                right='off')

ax1.plot(X, Y, color='b')
```

yields:
[No left ticks, all is well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqNiM.png)

If I try to use `.twinx()` to make another plot that shares the same y-axis and use the same methods I used on `ax1`, then the left ticks return:

```
... continuing the block above...

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax2.tick_params(axis='both',
                which='both',
                bottom='off',
                top='off',
                left='off',
                right='off')

ax2.plot(X, Z, color='r')
```

yields:
[The left ticks are back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5gOk.png)

I'm probably missing something simple, but I've been reading through documentation, playing with code, and looking through other posts to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: including `ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())` still doesn't get rid of the left ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue appears to be with the ordering of my commands.

If I move the `.twinx()` call above where I do my formatting, then the tick marks go away as I would like:

```
X = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
Y = np.sin(X)
Z = np.sin(2 * X)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_ylim([-1.1, 1.1])
ax2 = ax1.twinx() # <--------------- Move it here

ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax1.tick_params(axis='both',
                which='both',
                bottom='off',
                top='off',
                left='off',
                right='off')

ax1.plot(X, Y, color='b')

ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax2.tick_params(axis='both',
                which='both',
                bottom='off',
                top='off',
                left='off',
                right='off')

ax2.plot(X, Z, color='r')
```

yields what I want:
[No left tick marks!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi7Mr.png)

Thank you for getting me to question how I was plotting things, @Reggicide

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like below.

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining the figure and subplot like this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1)
```

and when setting the ytick labels for the second figure like this:

```
axes[1].set_yticklabels(axes[1].get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
```

This works for me when I'm plotting two figures side by side that share the same x and y labels.

Comment: I want the figures to be on top of each other, which is why I'm defining them one at a time and using `.twinx()` (which may not be the most elegant way of doing it; I would love to hear of a better way).

And my issue is with the tick marks themselves, not the labels. The labels behave as I want them to.

Comment: Then try fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2, sharex=True). But i suggested I think got rid of the tick marks and labels. If not I tried :)

Comment: Using the `sharex=True` kwarg still gave me side-by-side plots.

But thank you for your time :)

Comment: Sorry I probably mixed up the ncol and nrow inputs. But play around with those. I THINK it should be ncol=1, nrow=2 for what you want.